# Adobe edge animate: Audio starts playing even if preloader is there

Tags: audio, preloader, adobe-edge

**[when I am on slow internet connectivity or images are of larger size comes from server and taking time to load]**

Images taking time to load, so animation starts playing even if images are not loaded yet, to overcome this I have used preloader.

Now problem is audio I have used on this page loads early and starts playing even if page still showing preloader.
So it doesnt seem to work

**Que1:**
for images I have noticed until all assets are ready, edge min file attaches style

```
.edgeLoad-EDGE-137360589 { visibility:hidden; }
```

so for certain time it shows white screen as all other things it making hidden but animation runs in background, which doesnt look good.

**Que2:**
To resolve above issue, I tried preloader. By using it I can resolve above issue but it creates problem with audio.

Even if preloader is there, my audio starts playing in background.

[audio preload is set to false, but as and when it loads it starts playing not waiting for preloader to complete]

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you mean. What are you trying to do? What programming language are you using? What is your specific issue?

Comment: I have made a card in Adobe edge animate. Loading dynamic images(high  resolution) from server. So my card shows white screen as images not loaded yet which is my first issue..want some solution to overcome this, so to solve it i used preloader to make sure all assets loading first and then animation starts. So problem is music starts to play even if preloader is there and animation not started